# How to extract username and password in swagger-ui Authentication form

Tags: basic-authentication, swagger-ui

By searching, I got answer to add "req.headers.Authorization" as the following, but it is hard-coded username and password. I want to reuse the username and password in Authentication form to take input of username and password.

```
<!-- index.html -->

const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",

  requestInterceptor: (req) => {
    if (req.loadSpec) {

        // How to extract username and password in Authentication form? 
        req.headers.Authorization = 'Basic ' + btoa('user:password');

    }
    return req;
  },
  ...
})
```